# How can I use a boolean to substract a part of a bezier curve?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, boolean-modifier

I need to substract a part of a bezier curve with a boolean object.
Since I need to animate the part being removed, this needs to be dynamic.

There is no boolean modifier on curves,
and I’ve tested with Geometry Nodes (curve to mesh > mesh boolean) without managing to achieve it.

Does anyone knows how to do that ?

Comment: Do you also want to animate the curve?

Comment: Would you mind telling us how you tried it with _Geometry Nodes_? Because for me it works quite easy. You know you have to plug a _Profile Curve_ into the _Curve to Mesh_ node to get a mesh that works with _Mesh Boolean_?

Comment: Could you illustrate the desired result... what this Boolean is for? Alternatives might depend on that.  (Is the subtraction in the middle, at the ends, out of the side of a bevel... etc.etc.)

Answer (score 3):

A node set up like this allows me to Boolean difference a curve. Be sure that your Bezier curve has no bevel in object data properties. Otherwise, the geometry input would be a mesh and the Curve to Mesh node wouldn't work. Giving the curve depth has to be done in geometry nodes in this case. I used a Curve Circle.

[image]

Comment: If you have a _Bevel Depth_ on the curve it works, too. Then you can simply skip this whole _Curve to Mesh_ part and plug the _Group Input_ > _Geometry_ directly into the _Mesh Boolean_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yup, just make sure "Fill Caps" is enabled in the curve data, and to add a "Merge By distance" node before the boolean to prevent weird behaviour the default curve caps are not merged to the curve body

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Oh I see, do you know if I should correct this answer or leave as is?

Comment: @Gorgious You can do that if you want filled caps... but it is not necessary to make the _Mesh Boolean_ work.

Comment: @AdamSwearingen Well, your answer is not incorrect. The node setup works, the other option is just a different way to do it. And the _Mesh Boolean_ in your setup even works if you have a _Bevel Depth_, then the _Curve to Mesh_ just throws an error, will be ignored and instead the _Mesh Boolean_ uses the mesh from the _Bevel Depth_.

Comment: In fact, I've noticed that it seems to work, but that it depends on the origins and scale of the objects : I've got my mesh substracted, but at the wrong place.  Any idea on how to achieve this in "relative" mode ?  [See capture here](https://imgur.com/a/yzWCi3Y)